# Make Error 1 when trying to cross compile wiringPi C++ Eclipse

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse, arm, raspberry-pi

So I installed wiringPi onto my Raspberry Pi, I used the "./build" to make and install. I then didn't have the .h files in any of the include directories ("/usr/local/include" as an example) so I copied all of them into both "/usr/include" and into "/usr/local/include".

So I have been compiling for the Raspberry Pi already but when trying to do it with wiringPi I just get the Make *** [] Error 1.

After following what others instructed I ammended the command Eclipse uses
Cross G++ Compiler (Miscellanious):

```
-c -fmessage-length=0 -pthread -std=c++11 -Wl,--no-as-needed -lwiringPi -lwiringPiDev
```

Cross G++ Linker (Miscellanious):

```
-pthread -std=c++11 -Wl,--no-as-needed -lwiringPi -lwiringPiDev
```

In my "Include Paths (-l)" I have "/home/gummielovingmudkip/.local/share/raspberrypi/rootfs/usr/local/include"

Here is my main.cpp file

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <ctime>
#include <stdlib.h>

extern "C" {
    #include <wiringPi.h>
}

#include "Logging.hpp"

int main() {
    // Loading all necessary classes
    Logging log;

    // Beginning
    log.setup("susie");
    log.print(1, "main() has started");
    log.print(1, "All classes have been loaded");

    // Setting up wiringPi
    wiringPiSetup () ;

    // Setting pin modes
    pinMode (0, OUTPUT) ;

    for (;;) {
        digitalWrite (0, HIGH) ; delay (500) ;
        digitalWrite (0,  LOW) ; delay (500) ;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The above code gives no errors, I just get the compiler error.

I thank you all in advance.

Edit:
Sorry for not including the error message!

```
make: *** [Logging.o] Error 1
```

Comment: You need to show the actual _compiler_ error here - the error from Make just says "the step I just executed told me it failed, so I've stopped", and is thus useless for diagnosing the issue.

Comment: Thanks, I've amended my question